# Escolher o idioma do player em HTML5

Tags: html5, html5-video

Tenho um vídeo em dual áudio (inglês e português) porém quando minha página carrega o áudio fica somente em inglês.

```
<video width="200" height="200" controls>
  <source src="video/lucifer/T03E01.mkv" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/lucifer/T03E01.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Seu navegador não suporta tags de vídeo.
</video>
```

Preciso que ele reproduza o áudio em português.

Answer (score -1):

Creio que só seja possivel fazer essa manipulação através de JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

for (i=0; i < video.audioTracks.length; i++) {
  if (video.audioTracks[i].language.substring(0,2) === "pt-BR") { /*Alterar pela lingua que você quer*/
   video.audioTracks[i].enabled = true;
  } else {
   video.audioTracks[i].enabled = false;
  }
}

</script>
```